# animate text-align with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and have developed a simple resizing navigation menu using

```
$(this).stop().animate({width:170},"slow");
```

for the on hover effect.

My question is, how would i be able to add an animate effect to changing the text alignment.

I understand that this changes it:

```
$('.myElementClass').css('text-align','center');
```

but it looks ugly, and:

```
$(this).stop().animate({'text-align: left'}, "slow");
```

does'nt work at all.

Comment: I'm trying to animate text-align: justify to text-align: center on hover.

Is there really no way to do this yet?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use textAlign as it is not numeric and cannot be eased in between states.